# video streaming over LTE simulation

Tags: lte

Hello I  want to simulate a video streaming over LTE.I have tried SIMULTE but had problems in installing the ns-3 and the main problem is to know if it can support video streaming.Then I tried LTE-sim, but could not download the cygwin packages due to the internet speed which poor here in Algeria.

Can any one give me advice the best(which support video streaming) and easy( am no programmer) simuator to use?

Answer (score 0):

SIMULTE supports video streaming 
After a successful installation of Omnetpp and INET you will be able to simualte Video Streaming on Simulte
When you create your project you should indicate that the udpapp you are using is video streaming

Your .ini file should contain the following:

```
 **.cli[*].udpApp[*].typename = "UDPVideoStreamCli"
 #UDP application on the client side
 **.server.udpApp[*].typename = "UDPVideoStreamSvr"
 ##UDP application on the server side
```